# Is there a way to customize the details panel of a blueprint without going into C++ in Unreal?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am looking to customize the details panel of a blueprint class I have. Essentially, I have two objects that are exactly the same, but they use different types of variables to do the same thing. One essentially accesses a database to get the right information and the other is kind of a generic object that you don't use the database for.

I'm in the process of adding a bunch of these objects to my levels and for better accuracy and speed I would like to essentially put a Boolean in my details panel that shows or hides the correct information in the details panel.

Is there anyway to do this without getting into C++ code? I found this information about it in the documentation but, I don't really see a way to do it without going into C++.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/Slate/DetailsCustomization

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. You can only expose variables and components via blueprints, for everything else you need to create a C++ base class and set the correct flags for the UPROPERTY fields.